# KDB how to assign a value in root namespace from another namespace?

Tags: kdb

I have a table (feed_exclude) in the root namespace that I would like to reassign without changing to that namespace using \d .

```
>feed_exclude
feed      table
---------------
`feed1    `table1

\d .mon
`.[`feed_exclude],:flip enlist each first select feed,tab from 0!`.[`feed_table]
'2018.11.26T16:30:51.643 assign
```

How can I assign to a table in the root namespace `. without changing to the namespace using \d . ??

I have already checked that the meta of both sides of the assign operator is equivalent. The code executes correctly when the assign operator(:) is removed.

```
`.[`feed_exclude], flip enlist each first select feed,tab from 0!`[`feed_table]
feed      table
---------------
`feed1    `table1
`feed2    `table2
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
@[`.;`feed_exclude;,;flip enlist each first select feed,tab from 0!`.[`feed_table]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to refer to variables in the root namespace you can prepend a `..` to the symbolic name of the variable. In your case this would be`` `..feed_exclude ``.

You can then use `insert` to append to the table.

`` \d .mon
`..feed_exclude insert flip enlist each first select feed,tab from 0!`.[`feed_table] ``

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use upsert or insert and the symbol `.. notation to refer to root namespace

```
q)t:([]1 2 3)
q)\d .test
q.test)`..t upsert ([]10 20 30)
`..t
q.test)`..t insert ([]10 20 30)
6 7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use 'set' to update variables in global namespace:

```
q) `..feed_exclude set `.[`feed_exclude], flip enlist each first select feed,tab from 0!`[`feed_table]
```